# How can i fix DOM baclground gradient colors

Tags: javascript, dom-events

the color is not changing when i put an eventListner in input type = "color".

```
let css = document.querySelector("h3");
let color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
let color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
let body = document.getElementById("gradient");


color1.addEventListener("input", updateColor);

function updateColor() {
    body.style.background = `linear-gradient(to-right, ${color1.value}, ${color2.value})`;
}

color2.addEventListener("input", function () {
    body.style.background = `linear-gradient(to-right, ${color1.value}, ${color2.value})`;
});
```

Comment: Elaborate better and post errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `to right` not `to-right`. Also I have optimized your code. You could just use the same `updateColor()` function, for `color1` and `color2` inputs.

```js
let css = document.querySelector("h3");
let color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
let color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
let body = document.getElementById("gradient");


color1.addEventListener("input", updateColor);
color2.addEventListener("input", updateColor);

function updateColor() {
  body.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, ${color1.value}, ${color2.value})`;
}
```

```html
<body id="gradient">
  <h3>Gradient</h3>
  <input type="color" class="color1">
  <input type="color" class="color2">
</body>
```